# How to get m3u8 url from live streaming link

Tags: m3u8, m3u

how can I get direct stream link of live videos and play in VLC player. for example how should I get direct link of this link

http://nimlive3.giniko.com/arezotv/arezotv/chunklist_w700540206.m3u8?nimblesessionid=29374069&wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9My8zMC8yMDE4IDE6MDU6MTggUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT0zbzlyUlBGZzlBLzhrVkI4Z0lsRVdBPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTE0NDA=

Comment: Not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

wmsAuthSign=code

code is changing every time you refresh the page. u can get the link by get content in php but using local host not any server.